# String split() function not doing what's expected

Tags: python, split

I have a problem with split function — what I'm doing wrong here?
I get the error:
`not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` at the marked line.
The value in `line` is: `;Electronics:iPhone,3999;Galaxy,2999;Xiaomi,1999`.

After the first split, `newCategory` contains `"Electorincs"`, but `products` contains only `"i"`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

items = open("store.txt" , "r")
categories= dict()
for line in items:
    if line == '\n':
        break
    details= line.split(':')
    products=details[1]
    newCategory=details[0].lstrip
    categories[newCategory]=dict()
    products=products[0].split(';')
    for p in products:
        name,price=p.split(',')  # THIS LINE.
        name=name.lstrip
        price=price.lstrip
        categories[newCategory][name]=price
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is telling you? Your split is returning a list with only one element, and you are trying to unpack it into exactly two.

Comment: I know, and this is because the first split doesnt give ne the full sentence, only "i".

Answer (score 0):

OK, so look at your code, after reading the mentioned line, and splitting the code via ":", You have a list with 2 cells:
#0 contains: Electorincs
#1 contains: iPhone,3999;Galaxy,2999;Xiaomi,1999

SO by reading products[0] you're basically reading the first element of the string `iPhone,3999;Galaxy,2999;Xiaomi,1999`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace below line

```
products=products[0].split(';')
```

with

```
products=products.split(';')
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you tried to do however the for loop
"for line in items" meaning it brings you character after character and it might be part of the problem